# Android Emulator crash on sidebar click

Tags: android, crash, android-emulator

If I start the Emulator by clicking the "run app" Button in Android Studio 4.2.2 everything works fine till i try to use one of the emulator sidebar funktions, then the emulator will crash.

EventLog shows "Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554"

If i start the emulator from the comand line with "emulator @Pixel_3a_API_30" I can use the sidebar funktions without crashing the emualtor.

Did someone know a fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

1. the "problem" was that i was logged in as root for troubleshooting.
2. as a "normal" user emulator did not crash if i used the sidebar

If you need to android studio run as root:
write this in .bashrc or .zshrc

export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1

than the emulator should run from cli,
but will still crash if you choose it from the menu.
so I modified the menu command into

env QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1 "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f